# creating a class to hold global variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm developing an Object oriented program in javascript. Everything works just fine, but the problem is that I have too many global variable in my code.

The code :

```
var Item = function(name, price){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.sells = 0;
}


var sphagety = new Item ("sphagety", 130);
var pizza = new Item("pizza", 150);
var macaroni = new Item("macaroni", 100);
var milk = new Item("milk", 20);
var cheese = new Item("cheese", 15);

// too many global variable
var total = 0;
var change = 0;
var result = 0;
var sellRecord = []; 
var sumOfSell = [];

var cash = {
    "sum" : [],
    "display" : function(disp){

        if (disp === total) {
             console.log("Total : Rp" + total);

        }
         else if(disp === result){
            console.log("subTotal : Rp" + result);
        }
        else if(disp === change){
            console.log("change : Rp" + change + "\nmuch obliged");
        };

        },

     "sell" : function(req, qty){
        for(var property in req)
        sells = req;
        sells.sells += qty;
        result = req.price * qty;
        total += result; 
        cash.save();
        cash.display(total);
        cash.display(result);


    },
    "void" : function(){
          var lastSell = sumOfSell.length;
          var lastRec = sellRecord.length;
          total -= sumOfSell[lastSell-1];
          delete sellRecord[lastRec-1];
          delete sumOfSell[lastSell-1];
    },
    "save" : function(){
        cash.total += result;
        sumOfSell.push(result);
        sellRecord.push({sells});
     },
     "change" : function(money){


     if(money > total){
        change -= (money - total);
        cash.display(change);
    }
    else if(money == total){
         console.log("much obliged");
         }

    if(money < result){
         alert("the money is didn't enough!!\n  " + (money - result) + "");
        }   
     }
 }
 //  transaction no 1
 cash.sell(pizza,3);
 cash.sell(pizza,3);
 cash.sell(milk,3);
 cash.sell(cheese,3);
```

Then I'm trying to get rid of the global variable, I have an idea by making new class object called Session class and adding method endSession to cash Object, but I ended up stuck at figuring out how to handle closure between class.
I modified the code like this

```
// new Class (Session class) put the global variable inside
function Session (total, change, result, sellRecord, sumOfSell){
this.total = total;
this.change = change;
this.result = result;
this.sellRecord = sellRecord;
this.sumOfSell = sumOfSell;
}
 var cash = {
    "sum" : [],

    "display" : function(disp){

        if (disp === total) {
             console.log("Total : Rp" + total);

        }
         else if(disp === result){
            console.log("subTotal : Rp" + result);
        }
        else if(disp === change){
            console.log("change : Rp" + change + "\nmuch obliged");
        };

        },

     "sell" : function(req, qty){
        for(var property in req)
        sells = req;
        sells.sells += qty;
        Session.result = req.price * qty;
        Session.total += result; 
        cash.save();
        cash.display(total);
        cash.display(result);
    },
    // adding new cash method 
    "startSession" : function(){
        function session(){
            var session = {};
            var i = 1;
            session[i] = new Session(0,0,0,[],[]);
            //add
        }
     },
    "void" : function(){
          var lastSell = sumOfSell.length;
          var lastRec = sellRecord.length;
          total -= sumOfSell[lastSell-1];
          delete sellRecord[lastRec-1];
          delete sumOfSell[lastSell-1];
    },
    "save" : function(){
        cash.total += result;
        Session.sumOfSell.push(result);
        Session.sellRecord.push({sells});
     },
     "change" : function(money){


     if(money > total){
        change -= (money - total);
        cash.display(change);
    }
    else if(money == total){
         console.log("much obliged");
         }

    if(money < result){
         alert("the money is didn't enough!!\n  " + (money - result) + "");
        }   
     }
 }
```

I wonder if my idea is possible to do?

Comment: you should create an instance of that class. `var session = new Session( ... );`, then use `session.total`, `session.change`, ...

Comment: You seem to be over-engineering your solution, if you're okay with one global variable but not okay with many globals, just create a simple _Object_ to act as your namespace, and use it like any other object literal, e.g. `var myEnvironment = {};` then `myEnvironment.foo = 'hello';`, `console.log(myEnvironment.foo);` If you need the same values across multiple pages, see `window.sessionStorage`

Comment: I'm not sure how using a session resolves your issue with too many global variables. Sessions will help you store information across pages/ visits, but you still retain those variables.

Comment: Thanks for comments, @Amir I've tried that but still don't succeed,

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like this

```
function Session(){
    // These are private and can only be accessed via public methods
    var total = 0;
    // ....
    // Other local variables

    this.addProduct = function(item){
        total += item.price;
    }

    this.getTotal = function(){
        return total;
    }


}
```

Then you can do something like

```
var cart = new Session();
cart.add(new Item ("sphagety", 130));
cart.add(new Item("milk", 20));
console.log(cart.getTotal()); // 150
```

Remember to always use the new keyword in front of both `Session` and `Item` or you will have un desirable consequences.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessionStorage for this.

> sessionStorage stores the data only one session :) but if you stores
>   the date everytime you can use localStorage.

It is a simple sessionStorage example;
[using sessionStorage with browser support control](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_session)

Comment: This is not about how to store the objects

Comment: a html5 session storage just can hold string value, if I'm not wrong. Im trying to hold a sequence of actions it means hold arrays and other data type. I think I can't achieve this without database :/

Comment: @udnisap yes but he holds global variables with my answer?

Comment: I am assuming he is referring to `Session` as a container object just to hold the cart functionality.

Comment: @Robin actually you're wrong. You can hold other data types "like string" but data is not corrupted when you want to use.

Comment: OK guys, I think I'm just over doing it. this code is bad example of javascript programming, I'm just experimenting things..